# Handling Grafana metrics (mean, p25, p75, p90, p99, std) in Graphite

Tags: graphite, grafana

Grafana metrics in Graphite show up like the following:

[image]

In Graphite one configures storage aggregation in *storage-aggregation.conf*, what are the rules to configure for *p25, p75, p90, p99 and std* in that file?

Answer (score 1):

Since those values are already percentiles, there isn't really a sensible option for aggregating them over time.  The least-worst option for the purposes of drawing graphs is going to be to use the standard average aggregation function.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423535/way-to-aggregated-percentiles

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why, could you please clarify your point a bit more.

Comment: The page I linked to goes into some detail on why aggregating percentile values isn't mathematically correct.  The only way to correctly compute a percentile value for a given period is to take all the measurements for that period and do the math,. You can't divide the period up into chunks, calculate the percentile of each one and then average them, which is what trying to re-aggregate percentile numbers is doing.

Comment: Let me review that page and will follow up.